# About Master pages in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As ASP.NET application can have multile master pages, kindly want to know real life scenario where multile master pages applied

Answer (score 1):

Suppose an application which has various roles and the client wants to have different page layouts for each of them. In this scenario, you can have multiple master pages (one for each role).

This is just a simple scenario and there can be various others too. All this depends upon the project requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why you might choose to use multiple master pages in the same application:

- your website has multiple sections, and you would use a different master page for each section (e.g a a customer facing section and an administration section)
- your website might have different modes depending on the privileges of the user that is logged in and you decide to abstract the layout differences using master pages
- another possibility could be to use the master pages in conjunction with themes for additional customization capabilities

None of the above *require* multiple master pages (or the use of master pages at all, for that matter) but they are examples where one might choose to go with multiple master pages